# Histograms in SASmarkdown Not Output to PDF

Tags: sas, r-markdown

I am trying to run `SASmarkdown` in an Rmarkdown file being knit to PDF. I can get printed results to show as expected, but when I run the code below it opens up plots in SAS and nothing gets included in my PDF output. I can't seem to find an option to get this to correct itself.

````
```{r, engine='sas', engine.path=saspath, engine.opts=sasopts}
/* check for outliers */
proc univariate data=capstone.bigbostonc noprint;
   title1;
    var tract lon lat crim zn indus chas nox rm age dis rad 
        tax ptratio b lstat bostontown;
    histogram;
run;
```
````

Note, if I change the engine to `'sashtml'` and knit to HTML I get the plots as expected, just not with `engine='sas'` knit to PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't see any histogram in your PDF output is two-fold:

1. SASmarkdown only supports the LISTING and the HTML outputs (see reference below).
2. When you use the `noprint` option in your `proc univariate` statement
   you are removing the SAS listing output.

Item (1) follows from the extended documentation of the package (link referenced in the package documentation):
https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~hemken/SASworkshops/Markdown/SASmdpackage.html

where it says (**bold** added by me to highlight the relevant points):

> When you load the SASmarkdown package, six SAS engines are defined and
>   ready to use. They all run your SAS code, but return different output
>   into your document. These are
>
> **sas - this returns the SAS code you ran and ordinary ("listing")
>   output**
>
> saslog - this returns the SAS log instead of your code, and ordinary
>   SAS output
>
> **sashtml - this returns SAS code and SAS HTML output**
>
> sashtmllog - this returns the SAS log and SAS HTML output
>
> sashtml5 - this returns SAS code and SAS HTML output with inline
>   graphics
>
> sashtml5log - this returns the SAS log and SAS HTML output

As for (2), given that you cannot send HTML output to a PDF file, I would say the only option you have in order to include some kind of plot with the distribution of your variables in the PDF output is to generate the plots in the listing output. In that case, you would see a stem-and-leaf plot instead of a histogram.

You can do the following to achieve that:

- disable `ods graphics` using the statement `ods graphics off;`,
- add the `plots` option to the `proc univariate` statement.

This setup follows from the `PROC UNIVARIATE` documentation:

> PLOTS | PLOT< (   ) >  produces a
>   panel of plots for each analysis variable. If ODS Graphics is enabled,
>   the panel contains a horizontal histogram,a box plot, and a normal
>   probability plot. Otherwise, the procedure produces a stem-and-leaf
>   plot (or a horizontal bar chart),a box plot, and a normal probability
>   plot by using line printer output.

I used the following code to test this and it worked as expected:

````
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

indoc <- '
---
title: "Stem and leaf plot generated in LISTING output"
output: pdf_document
---

# Setup
```{r}
library(SASmarkdown)
sasexe <- "C:/Program Files/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sas.exe"
sasopts <- "-nosplash -ls 75"
```

```{r SteamAndLeafPlots, engine="sas", engine.path=sasexe, engine.opts=sasopts}
ods graphics off;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class plots;
  var age;
run;
ods graphics on;
```
'

knitr::knit(text=indoc, output="test.md")
rmarkdown::render("test.md")
````

The partial PDF output is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I could get this to output just the stem-and-leaf and/or boxplots?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and I don't think you will find a way to do it. In fact, those plots are legacy plots (see here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=procstat&docsetTarget=procstat_univariate_details26.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en). Normally, to customize output generated by SAS you would modify the template on which the output is based (using `PROC TEMPLATE` for graphical output and `PROC ODSTABLE` for ODS output).

Comment: You would identify what template to modify by running `ods trace on;` just before running the procedure and taking those names from the log. If you try that with your `PROC UNIVARIATE` run you would see something like this: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p6jfpabr/univariateLocation-Path-UnivariatetnfaverTestsFor-Location-Output-Added-Name/ Here we see that the "Plots" output responsible for the stem-leaf, etc. in the line printer output do NOT show up as a template but as a "Data Name" (check the line `Data Name:  BatchOutput`). I don't know how to modify that `BatchOutput` format...

Comment: Thanks. I was able to realize another work around that saved time. I just had a whole bunch of plots and didn't want to get into save and insert for every one of them. Turned out, R Studio saves the plots that are popping up in SAS when I knit to PDF. Then was able to fashion an `\includegraphics` tag as needed.

Comment: Excellent! Could you post an answer with your code so that we can all see the solution? Perhaps you meant the `include_graphics()` function? (rdrr.io/cran/knitr/man/include_graphics.html)

Comment: I'll get something up when back at my computer. I'm using the `\includegraphics` TeX tag, but I may go back and look at using the `include_graphics()` function in R. I'd completely forgot about that.